# Can't Call Value of non Function Type 'AWSSNS'

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

i am using AWSNS in my application which is written in Swift 3.0. I am facing this `Can't Call Value of non Function Type 'AWSSNS'` error in a line of code in my register function.

Following is my code:

```
 func myfunction(){
    initial()
    let tkn = nd.value(forKey: "devicetoken") as! String
    var myArn: String = myARN

    var platformEndpointRequest = AWSSNSCreatePlatformEndpointInput()
    platformEndpointRequest?.customUserData = "MyUserID;iPhone7"
    platformEndpointRequest?.token = tkn

    platformEndpointRequest?.platformApplicationArn = SNSPlatformApplicationArn
//var snsManager.... this line below is giving error
        var snsManager = AWSSNS()(configuration: configuration)
        var endpt = snsManager.createPlatformEndpoint(platformEndpointRequest)

    }
```

I will be thankful if someone helps.

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be `AWSSNS(configuration...`?

Comment: let me try this one.

Comment: Vadian, i changed it to the one you suggested and now it is saying "change configuration to forKey". I don't know what key is this asking for. Look here [IMAGE](https://ibb.co/iHCYBa)

Comment: I'm not familiar with AWSNS. Please read the documentation of the API.

Answer (score 0):

**It works for me:**

```
 let sns = AWSSNS.defaultSNS()
 let request = AWSSNSCreatePlatformEndpointInput()
 request.token = deviceTokenString
        request.platformApplicationArn = SNSPlatformApplicationArn
        sns.createPlatformEndpoint(request).continueWith(executor: AWSExecutor.mainThreadExecutor(), block: { (task: AWSTask!) -> AnyObject! in
            if task.error != nil {
                print("Error: \(task.error)")
            } else {
                let createEndpointResponse = task.result as! AWSSNSCreateEndpointResponse
                print("endpointArn: \(createEndpointResponse.endpointArn)")
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(createEndpointResponse.endpointArn, forKey: "endpointArn")
            }

            return nil
        })
```

Comment: Thanks Salman, I tried that but no endpointArn is being generated. console shows this: `Error: Optional(Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSSNSErrorDomain Code=0 "(null)")`

Comment: see this for more help:- https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/blob/master/SNS-MobileAnalytics-Sample/Swift/Sample_SNS_MobileAnalytics/AppDelegate.swift